# Combining LPAD and RPAD

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to pad two words from DUAL and pad the left side as `***` and the right side as `!!!`.

> ORACLE SQL: Error at line 1/66: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found
> where expected

My code:

```
SELECT RPAD(LPAD('Cupcake', 'Time', 14, '*'), 17, '!') AS padded phrase FROM DUAL
```

Result needed: `***Cupcake Time!!!`

Comment: **1.** `LPAD` takes 3 parameters, but you have 4 parameters. Perhaps you meant `LPAD('Cupcake Time', 14, '*')` **2.** Your column alias `padded phrase` is two words and you can't just write words with spaces in them and expect oracle to know what you mean. Instead `AS "padded phrase"` or even better `AS padded_phrase`.

Comment: Thank you Mr. JNevill! Worked well. SELECT RPAD(LPAD('CupcakeTime', 14, '*'), 17, '!') AS padded_phrase FROM DUAL - Result: ***CupcakeTime!!!

Comment: I'd probably use concatenation instead.

Comment: Thanks jarih! Excellent advice. SELECT LPAD('Cupcake', LENGTH('Cupcake')+3, '*')||' '||RPAD('Time', 7, '!') AS padded_phrase
FROM DUAL;
FROM DUAL;. Result: ***Cupcake Time!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this but why I don't know :-)

```
Select LPAD('Cupcake', 10, '*') || RPAD(' Time', 8, '!') AS padded_phrase 
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate `Cupcake` and `Time` with a space between them and them pad.

You also need the identifier to be a single word so `padded_phrase` or to use a quoted identifier `"padded phrase"` (but quoted identifiers are generally considered bad practice).

```sql
SELECT RPAD(LPAD('Cupcake' || ' ' || 'Time', 15, '*'), 18, '!')
         AS padded_phrase
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

| PADDED_PHRASE |
| --- |
| ***Cupcake Time!!! |

Or, if you always want 3 `*`s before and 3 `!`s after then don't pad, just concatenate string literals:

```sql
SELECT '***' || 'Cupcake' || ' ' || 'Time' || '!!!' AS padded_phrase
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

| PADDED_PHRASE |
| --- |
| ***Cupcake Time!!! |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qlvj-jez)